# is there an equivalent of R's nls in statsmodels?

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

Does `statsmodels` support nonlinear regression to an arbitrary equation? (I know that there are some forms that are already built in, e.g. for logistic regression, but I am after something more flexible)

In the solution https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44249 to a question about non-linear regression, 
the code is in `R` and uses the function `nls`. There it has the equation's parameters defined with `start = list(a1=0, ...)`.   These are of course just some initial guesses and not the final fitted values. But what is different here compared to `lm` is that the parameters don't need to be from the columns of the input data.

I've been able to use `statsmodels.formula.api.ols` as an equivalent for R's `lm`, but when I try to use it with an equation that has parameters (and not weights for the inputs / combinations of inputs), statsmodels complains about the parameters not being defined. It does not seem to have an equivalent argument as `start=` so it isn't obvious how to introduce them.

Is there a different class or function in `statsmodels` that accepts definition of these initial parameter values?

EDIT:

My current attempt and also workaround following suggestion with lmfit

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def eqn_poly(x, a, b):
    ''' simple polynomial '''
    return  a*x**2.0 + b*x
def eqn_nl(x, a, b):
    ''' fractional equation '''
    return  1.0 / ((a+x)*b)

x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.1)
y1 = eqn_poly(x, 0.1, 0.5)
y2 = eqn_nl(x, 0.1, 0.5)

sigma  =0.05
y1_noise = y1 + sigma * np.random.randn(*y1.shape)
y2_noise = y2 + sigma * np.random.randn(*y2.shape)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([x, y1_noise]).T, columns= ['x', 'y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([x, y2_noise]).T, columns= ['x', 'y'])

res1 = ols("y ~ 1 + x + I(x ** 2.0)", df1).fit()
print res1.summary()

res3 = ols("y ~ 1 + x + I(x ** 2.0)", df2).fit()
#res2 = ols("y ~ eqn_nl(x, a, b)", df2).fit()
# ^^^ this fails if a, b are not initialised ^^^
# so initialise a, b
a,b = 1.0, 1.0
res2 = ols("y ~ eqn_nl(x, a, b)", df2).fit()
print res2.summary()
# ===> and now the fitting is bad, it has an intercept -4.79, and a weight
# on the equation 15.7.
```

Giving `lmfit` the formula it is able to find parameters.

```
import lmfit
mod = lmfit.Model(eqn_nl)
lm_result = mod.fit(y2_noise, x=x, a=1.0, b=1.0)
print lm_result.fit_report()
# ===> this one works fine, a=0.101, b=0.4977
```

But trying to put y1, x into ols doesn't seem to work ("PatsyError: model is missing required outcome variables"). I didn't really follow that suggestion.

Comment: Please show your attempt. Simply calculate `Y` and `X` variables and pass as `sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()`.

Comment: statsmodels currently does not have nonlinear least squares. But lmfit is a good package for it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lmfit/

Comment: @user333700 ... you can pass [nonlinear models](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html#OLS-non-linear-curve-but-linear-in-parameters) in sm.OLS or sm.WLS

Comment: Nonlinear least squares, nls, refers to `nonlinear in parameters` which is not supported by OLS or WLS, Also, scipy has curve_fit for simple usecases.

Answer (score 1):

consider [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) as desired R.nls-like function

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33035545)